# Join three Tables with 2 different Columns

Tags: sql-server, join

Here is the thing:

I have three tables:

**Table1:**
COL1 COL2
**Table2:**
COL2 COL3
**Table3:**
COL3 COL4

And I want to select the COL4 from `Table3` when `Table.COL3 = TABLE2.COL3`, which the `Table2.COL3` from when `Table2.COL2 = Table1.COL2`

It likes two join table, but when I use the following query it doesn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM 
         table3
         INNER JOIN table2 ON table3.col3 
         =
         ( 
          SELECT  table2.col3
                  FROM table2
                  INNER JOIN table1 ON 
                  table1.col2 = table2.col2
         )
```

Comment: NO NEED TO SHOUT AT US! Please stop using **ALL CAPS** - it's very hard to read, it's annoying, and it's considered **SHOUTING** at your audience - rude and unwelcome. Stop doing this - please.

Comment: `FROM table3.col4` you never select with a column name in the from.

Comment: Really sorry for all caps. I didn't mean to that.

Comment: What was the error you got from your query that didn't work?  This is very basic sql and usually the error message will lead you to a solution with a little research.

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting from table1 joining to the others.  So table1 goes in the from.

```
SELECT TABLE3.col4
FROM TABLE1
JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE2.COL2 = TABLE1.COL2
JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE3.COL3= TABLE2.COL3
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first table in the join statement. You have used a column name i.e. table3.col4 in stead of a table name i.e. table3. So, it's giving error.

Your correct query will be as follows

```
SELECT table3.col4 FROM table3
INNER JOIN table2 
ON table3.col3 =
 ( SELECT  table2.col3
 FROM table2
 INNER JOIN table1 ON 
 table1.col2 = table2.col2)
```